# Can I know what causes Segmentation Fault here?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I think I have implemented the pointer correctly in below code. But it causes Segmentation fault. Can someone explain why?

```
struct list
{
    int index;
    struct list *next;
};
void add(struct list *l,int index)
{
    struct list *temp=l;
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        temp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        temp->index=index;
        temp->next=NULL;
        l=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
        struct list *nnode=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        nnode->index=index;
        nnode->next=NULL;
        temp->next=nnode;
    }
}

main()
{
        struct list *l;
        l=NULL;
        int el;
        scanf("%d",&el);
        add(l,el);
        while(l->next!=NULL)    //It causes seg fault
        {
            printf(" %d ",l->index);
            l=l->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: What happened to the indenting in your code? Also, what is `el`?

Comment: @cnicutar Yes! Its just a part of the whole code.

Comment: Posting part is okay, but if it's intended to be a standalone program and you're asking about a *runtime* error, please make sure that what you're posting actually *compiles* first.

Comment: Also, make sure that the code you post actually demonstrates the problem you're having. Your code, now that it compiles, does not segfault.

Comment: Thanks, your code now demonstrates the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
void add(struct list *l,int index)
{
    struct list *temp=l;
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        temp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        temp->index=index;
        temp->next=NULL;
        l=temp;
    }
...
```

the parameter l will not change since you are just passing it as a pointer, in order to change what l points to you need to pass the address of l

```
void add(struct list **l,int index)
{
    struct list *temp;
    if(*l==NULL)
    {
        temp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        temp->index=index;
        temp->next=NULL;
        *l=temp;
    }
...
```

otherwise the change will not reach outside the function scope.

Comment: But in question, l is declared as pointer and its address is sent to add. That should work with the address. no?

Comment: imagine it like this, if you write a function foo(int a) and you set a to a value in the function a will not have changed when you leave the function. if you write foo(int* a) you may change the value of what a points to but not what it points to, that needs yet another level of indirection

Comment: That is ok.. But in "struct list *temp=l;" here value of l ie. address of struct is sent to temp. Is it wrong?

Comment: temp will just be set to point to the same thing l points to, but what you want to achieve is to change what l points to i.e. the new allocated struct.

Answer (score 2):

This code shouldn't segfault if you just call add once, but I assume you call other functions and pass the list which is still `NULL` you should send a pointer to pointer to the list instead

```
void add(struct list **l,int index)
{
    if(*l==NULL) {
        *l=(struct list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    }
}
```

Otherwise it will still be `NULL` when add returns, because you only initialize a copy of the pointer, or if this confuses you could just initialize the list in `main()` and avoid initialization in `add()`

Comment: With a single-level pointer, what makes it wrong? Even now it should work with the address and change its value from NULL. no?

Comment: @vivek_jonam no a copy of the pointer is sent and initialized, the pointer in main is still `NULL`

Comment: In "struct list *temp=l;" What I understood is l's address is sent to temp as l is a pointer. Is it wrong?

Comment: In "struct list *temp=l;" here value of l ie. address of struct is sent to temp. Is it wrong?

Comment: @vivek_jonam yes, sort of, but `l` is `NULL` so temp is `NULL` then you allocate memory for the *local pointer* `l` and use it but not the one in the `main()`